# How to give create a bar graph using D3 where each individual bar is a different color?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to create a bar graph in D3, I have already made the graph and it turned out ok, but now I have to have it so that each bar in the graph is a different color. Right now they are all blue since I set a color attribute on them to be blue but I was wondering how to make each bar a different color.

```
    var bars = chart.append('g')
    .attr('id', "bars-container");

    bars.selectAll('.bar')
    .data(regions)
    .enter().append("rect")
        .attr('class', "bar")
        .attr('x', function(d){
            return xScale(d.region);
        })
        .attr('y', function(d){
            return yScale(+d.sales); 
        })
        .attr('width', xScale.bandwidth())
        .attr('height', function(d){return barsHeight-yScale(+d.sales);})
        .style('fill', "blue");

    bars.attr('transform', 'translate('+axisMargin+',0)');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way of doing it

```
// Define the following 
 var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10);//This creates 10 different colors

...
// Where you color the bars use this
.attr("fill", function(d, i){
return color(i);})
```

You can control the colors by creating an array of colors inside `d3.scaleOrdinal()`

Comment: Thank you very much, I will try this out

Comment: I have to make a call in the script tag to the chromatic module for D3 for this correct?